# How to compare geometry viewport from object to map active window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show markers on map, only if geometry.viewport on my object is match to map window.

So, I began to create map bounds and comparing with geometry.viewport when map is drag/zoom to show marker if viewport match on map window, but my marker didn't show.

Is it posible to comparing map bounds to geometry.viewport from my object?

```js
var map,
  infowindow,
  latlngbounds;

var myData = {
  "results": [{
    "ATM": [{
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.187688000000001,
            "lng": 106.815248
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.186168469708499,
              "lng": 106.8167501802915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.188866430291504,
              "lng": 106.8140522197085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/atm-71.png",
        "id": "a3accb50985678d7589f712fea5252ef0be7651a",
        "name": "Lippo Bank",
        "place_id": "ChIJC5p3Jp32aS4RNV2CNGY_bkI",
        "reference": "CmRRAAAAgSqsFrQBWNCZyAlRULRhSxUimo1oGOixfr-acHJA7-CcQZhHMzDUfy7YG1g7RKYiBe0owH-gRpq03Z_k_q6hzNX_-XZ6w-zbaoZitCLwRod_IHF6xDYcxb5r9o4oE_8wEhBdKhGKDev1-eD1h83BxEuPGhRbIJYGEzHEx8Efd8xYH29o6j6PaA",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": ["atm", "finance", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
        "vicinity": "Pasar Tanah Abang, Jalan Fachrudin No.5, Kampung Bali",
        "category": "atm"
      },
      {
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.166333700000001,
            "lng": 106.8031611
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.164964969708497,
              "lng": 106.8045088802915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.167662930291502,
              "lng": 106.8018109197085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/atm-71.png",
        "id": "a73fadf83bd003c0623aaa0cbdfc9ddb9412ba5d",
        "name": "BCA",
        "place_id": "ChIJtXHoeG_2aS4RG3yyAdj4ph4",
        "rating": 2,
        "reference": "CmRRAAAA8zCEbvfTRyBVHPTV64Den19_zYpUtWr4eEJED31xFn7Z6oXfUJwwSrJmYjZct8IofG60DLYDxk5uHXixHWNYSyuazzzLUnUpA3aTPXttYHaROfqvRBpC76Dd9OP60SVdEhBK3EeYj6DxyYjaqnwHTA1rGhSwe3IYepu-EPz3rVYzGejybdH2VA",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": ["atm", "finance", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
        "vicinity": "Jalan Kh. Hasyim Ashari No.Lt. Dasar, No., RW.8, Cideng",
        "category": "atm"
      },
      {
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.16088,
            "lng": 106.83252
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.159531019708498,
              "lng": 106.8338689802915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.162228980291502,
              "lng": 106.8311710197085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/atm-71.png",
        "id": "b2b350cf75380825292d35f17bdc5c0167b780c0",
        "name": "BCA",
        "place_id": "ChIJNTIagMT1aS4RfmpinPMUO9g",
        "rating": 5,
        "reference": "CmRSAAAAOisT3gDmVlNzyWdT1IMNLV2GnBd-KbbsnL0-OD16JdEjSJY_nQKDVWFNYXTDgRvoDB7IrWE6AOoTQc6_aVGC3vYWb_hGfTjfxtOsV_pdKcha_e0cBUeyNMqak20OXtLbEhCoSm_Sw-wqbfW0dXoxnFujGhSu-TW5gIJrJ-LNJUDmgw7HVwGfHQ",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": ["atm", "finance", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
        "vicinity": "Pasar Metro, Jl. Kh. Samanhudi No.Lt.1, RT.3/RW.6, Pasar Baru",
        "category": "atm"
      }
    ],
    "Restaurant": [{
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -6.177284299999998,
          "lng": 106.800065
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -6.175935319708497,
            "lng": 106.8014139802915
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -6.178633280291501,
            "lng": 106.7987160197085
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
      "id": "2bad9fd476e1f228888b12718a2b16688c239c9c",
      "name": "Domino's Pizza Indonesia",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true,
        "weekday_text": []
      },
      "photos": [{
        "height": 2448,
        "html_attributions": [
          "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104847677816323088483/photos\"\u003eMetta Pranata\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA9_A-JNmp_F1pAfw1LfyQIzmbZ0CyEHAP85Bu6cVIpBZyOpjJf7r5jHLsaI4lI1JU-kUp6PSIGE3nelvcBbyibFHriRteg4T24cUy5cFfFXctazlvrkRJGWoUpp1fpYlCEhCF6Kqv_SyPan3ZQwlcsu2MGhSo7czKonbhbMpLFo49wqPGAnkPQA",
        "width": 3264
      }],
      "place_id": "ChIJq7oXAIr2aS4RtPo-KxshLHQ",
      "price_level": 1,
      "rating": 4.1,
      "reference": "CmRRAAAAIPD7F3cb2jopx91PUhhqxpu4b8SNC8toZMp8IFZSsj2tjzv0fWogLIyx6GLrUIji7kC3i3zQSK99OEu9uZHuSurn0c6RZjhfHfOfFld89sWaGgoCjpckO99uTFBhzeUzEhBEYlvMHgNaYi1dcg0wGoaGGhQBPFeTSa_ejqXyAmJuuYL2f6c9nA",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
        "meal_delivery",
        "meal_takeaway",
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "Jalan Tomang Raya No. 32 Blok B11 Kav. 39, Jatipulo, Palmerah, RT.5/RW.1, Jatipulo",
      "category": "restaurant"
    }],
    "School": [{
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.1795373,
            "lng": 106.7991026
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.178036219708497,
              "lng": 106.8003758802915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.180734180291502,
              "lng": 106.7976779197085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png",
        "id": "fbacddf46e05f548cbbfe0dc4ba670ad012a1218",
        "name": "Sekolah Dasar Negeri Jati Pulo 07 Pagi",
        "photos": [{
          "height": 1440,
          "html_attributions": [
            "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111303697514616849044/photos\"\u003eGb Jkt\u003c/a\u003e"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAfm0ln5twhqqMELlbZ2Jc2YGq5DvTOPZoXdy1Zop6lbeol_4uYjPnrK38k75DHIEL2zBIYMbm6Hgru2UBmDXRwUQFbH7kbFNSEHdZ6bWW8c9RfIb3ElKBn1hZY6F-yPEIEhCXy7avCBaVVULc4ngZa2fUGhTFzHdwiOgjejPYgf-QiV_d1bN75Q",
          "width": 2560
        }],
        "place_id": "ChIJmdYuN4r2aS4RDUwPBrQtgyA",
        "rating": 4,
        "reference": "CmRRAAAAt7mhFoZeaukhSfR6MfkxDE5-_tgsqSFA_1LIOiiaYwyryetUsB4YAR-RaPhvU6-bh9XysOp0IFUFVQA8GEl06opmI_Mv08--56zbT0nKcFZ95f-4V3wApC1IlCqXluX8EhB0oI-9p5LqUM-8S5ohJAn9GhSjylq2coBRTkQ6iPqPlgyOw36VgA",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": ["school", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
        "vicinity": "Jalan Teratai No.17, RT.4/RW.1, Jatipulo",
        "category": "school"
      },
      {
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.1812008,
            "lng": 106.7856261
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.179857319708496,
              "lng": 106.7869020302915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.182555280291501,
              "lng": 106.7842040697085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png",
        "id": "c2c219444c5a0ebe4a3cc3a1c7ba8aeac887fb94",
        "name": "Sekolah Dasar Negeri Tanjung Duren Selatan 05 Pagi",
        "place_id": "ChIJRabUAvf2aS4RH0yq3DzuydE",
        "rating": 4.2,
        "reference": "CmRSAAAAvG63rooM19T3RKVu_7c9yjj7_Ipzshl1OOUrnLKJZjgTyKb9GJrH1l62Ie9CQFN0BmZX_5KpSc0LoN46xLXy9k2GRP-6hWkWQwxJln4SKdMPNvFPnk6EhQ_3zyoYX6vHEhDZKLj8nSSQZRhYEqKSxLnsGhQrIDHxFabEN0KtvVM6DvkL_e6aDQ",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": ["school", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
        "vicinity": "Jalan Tanjung Duren Dalam IV No.26, RT.3/RW.3, Tanjung Duren Selatan",
        "category": "school"
      }
    ],
    "Convenience_Store": [{
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.1675108,
            "lng": 106.7955641
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.166144019708497,
              "lng": 106.7968599302915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.168841980291502,
              "lng": 106.7941619697085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
        "id": "fdfd8c6c1f5381d1558b77010445c1bfb72b2ac0",
        "name": "Alfamart",
        "opening_hours": {
          "open_now": true,
          "weekday_text": []
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJN9dNcln2aS4RYSdYc1koi4w",
        "reference": "CmRSAAAA7ky5vQ0XtVUu8GEC7fuJUpmYc2cl3GiOspV6fQbPOggcUmopf1Ic0MqB658pBjcwWjuTDb7K3Errw4kyT08WbZJGoB-tZAz_DR3bWjaISERDUC2-O7ehXNsVpKevgyp2EhDuyH5Pur2itPZM92e5d6H-GhSZPYJLKH8aPfyKEgkZJBZX3vu-7g",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": [
          "convenience_store",
          "food",
          "store",
          "point_of_interest",
          "establishment"
        ],
        "vicinity": "Jalan Tawakal Raya RT.3/RW.9, Tomang",
        "category": "conveniencestore"
      },
      {
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": -6.1758259,
            "lng": 106.7981367
          },
          "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
              "lat": -6.174526069708498,
              "lng": 106.7995251802915
            },
            "southwest": {
              "lat": -6.177224030291502,
              "lng": 106.7968272197085
            }
          }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
        "id": "ce03dfc58a9776220ba205c38d1957a9526b889a",
        "name": "Alfamart",
        "opening_hours": {
          "open_now": true,
          "weekday_text": []
        },
        "photos": [{
          "height": 2940,
          "html_attributions": [
            "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102054846689288140361/photos\"\u003eBata Expose Indonesia\u003c/a\u003e"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAApDL_kUQ46OPPGLyRF_wU_o1HIXHMtith4KfzJ5d1Tu8qd8YgfjMq_haUN4qB8mYfF3JJP2GDCm_Xu-A1RwxwCywuv_ogUYuY4oSfbKINy1DQcYi7VoebjmhapSVrkHsiEhDNzI7lLqjUE-mf__uNx9pMGhSdi89tZBDuZyWl0qqc3leDXE0KMA",
          "width": 3920
        }],
        "place_id": "ChIJT9oDuWH2aS4Rn8NUqTJCoXg",
        "rating": 5,
        "reference": "CmRRAAAArHa0QxrDI2b5UbQPrPbEYKjhj1BKdyg7zqmbX6Y4c13LSG-5rUz5kCZ_QqSPW9ZzczzdYMQ4b9PaJxt7el-yQgXmQork4kH33ctcKLVD-J3Mf873ET7ICne6qpY3AnTWEhDUY6jTBsnRcNHo4U-goOCUGhTDvd2WGmkZdtFQpfG3R4hdw13uQw",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": [
          "convenience_store",
          "food",
          "store",
          "point_of_interest",
          "establishment"
        ],
        "vicinity": "Jalan Gelong Baru, RT. 11/02, Tomang, Grogol petamburan, RT.11/RW.2, Tomang",
        "category": "conveniencestore"
      }
    ],
    "Shelter": [{
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -6.165864,
          "lng": 106.790138
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -6.164515019708498,
            "lng": 106.7914869802915
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -6.167212980291502,
            "lng": 106.7887890197085
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png",
      "id": "bee1b888faccd80390916b0db9eee48b23d97997",
      "name": "Kramat Djati. PT - Grogol",
      "place_id": "ChIJrXP6vkL2aS4RZzma9Io9SLU",
      "reference": "CmRSAAAATLmMwXMvt-4ETiEyVY0hCF60GDdinc_Da41B3WXy5w0TyQPDSewMSAVt9DRCGFoelfWi043QJOxDcoevR12exizcBpPWUtsZw7d0NGZg2I4hUHQy3gLXFBXNufcnKFweEhD5mNIc6BPjg3nPIaP0yr9oGhRMqcxj-MUhTuDS-bCask2Q0kRpDA",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
        "bus_station",
        "transit_station",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "JL. Doktor Susilo Raya No.16, Grogol - West Jakarta 11460",
      "category": "shelter"
    }]
  }]
}

function initMap() {
  // determine current location
  lat = -6.174241;
  lng = 106.798064;
  pyrmont = {
    lat: parseFloat(lat),
    lng: parseFloat(lng)
  };
  // end


  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 16,
    scrollwheel: false
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: parseFloat(lat),
      lng: parseFloat(lng)
    }
  });

  latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    latlngbounds = map.getBounds();
    ne = latlngbounds.getNorthEast();
    sw = latlngbounds.getSouthWest();
    $("#lat-north .value").html(ne.lat());
    $("#lng-east .value").html(ne.lng());
    $("#lat-south .value").html(sw.lat());
    $("#lng-west .value").html(sw.lng());
    //var neLat = $("#lat-north .value").html(ne.lat()).text();

    $.each(myData.results, function(index, obj) {
      $.each(obj, function(idx, arr) {
        $.each(arr, function(key, val) {


          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.geometry.location);
          if (latlngbounds > val.geometry.viewport) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              icon: {
                url: val.icon,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30)
              },
              title: val.name
            });
            return false;
          } else {
            return false;
          }

        });
      });
    });
  });

}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBrFkA5CJ2KDHXX_DhTZMlqDAtvocKv3eg&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map">
</div>
<div id="bound">
  <div id="lat-north" class="line">
    <div class="name">neLat</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lng-east" class="line">
    <div class="name">neLng</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lat-south" class="line">
    <div class="name">swLat</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lng-west" class="line">
    <div class="name">swLng</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [LatLngBounds class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds), you probably need the `intersects` method.  Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    latlngbounds = map.getBounds();
    ne = latlngbounds.getNorthEast();
    sw = latlngbounds.getSouthWest();
    $("#lat-north .value").html(ne.lat());
    $("#lng-east .value").html(ne.lng());
    $("#lat-south .value").html(sw.lat());
    $("#lng-west .value").html(sw.lng());

    $.each(myData.results, function(index, obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(idx, arr) {
            $.each(arr, function(key, val) {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    val.geometry.viewport.southwest,
                    val.geometry.viewport.northeast
                );

                if (latlngbounds.intersects(bounds)) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: val.geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        icon: {
                            url: val.icon,
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30)
                        },
                        title: val.name
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```